# Forgot Facebook Email and Password

Tags: facebook, account-recovery, facebook-account

I have an old Facebook account that I created, uploaded a couple of photos and simply ignored (i.e. no friends added). Now, I can't remember the email address associated with the account and I don't remember the password either. How can I find out which email address I had associated with that account?

P.S. I have created a new Facebook account and my picture can be used to identify me (if I can get someone at Facebook to take a look). Other than that, I'm willing to have that old account deleted altogether if recovery isn't possible.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. Your last option would be to use this form http://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=320596411317906

If you cannot remember the email address then you cannot get in.

(Though if you know all the email addresses you own then it's a process of elimination really)

Comment: Link points to "This Page Isn't Available"

Answer (score 2):

Just find your old account and report it. Or go though this link:

https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=174210519303259

Or try this one:

http://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=320596411317906

Comment: Second link returns "This Page Isn't Available"