# Recovery of account when been blocked

Tags: facebook, account-recovery

Facebook has blocked my account without any notice. How can I recover my account?

Comment: Related [1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74246/88163), [2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/29082/88163)

Comment: This question was bumped by an answer deleted due to being flagged as spam.

Answer (score 4):

In some cases Facebook may not issue a warning before disabling your account. Also note that Facebook don't restore accounts that were disabled for severe violations of the [Facebook Community Standards](https://www.facebook.com/communitystandards/).

From [Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/103873106370583/?ref=u2u):

> Facebook [disable accounts](https://www.facebook.com/help/185747581553788/) that don't follow the [Facebook Terms](https://www.facebook.com/terms). Some examples include:
>
> - Posting content that doesn't follow the Facebook Terms
> - Using a fake name
> - Impersonating someone
> - Continuing behavior that's not allowed on Facebook by violating our Community Standards
> - Contacting other people for the purpose of harassment, advertising, promoting, dating or other conduct that's not allowed
>
> If you think your account was disabled by mistake, please [submit an appeal](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/260749603972907).

Answer (score -2):

- In case some of your friends reported your posts contains abusive or
  inappropriate, your account can be blocked.
- Maybe you have tried to login your account with the wrong credentials
  several times.
- Multiple device logins can lead to account block.